# Adding custom fields to the header.php

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, custom-header

I want to add advanced custom fields/custom fields to my header.php as it contains text and phone numbers that we may change - I have tried referencing them but it didn't work. I have also Googled and not found a solution yet.

I want to be able to edit the content of the fields from my home page, so I am thinking that might be what I am doing wrong?

When I reference the advanced custom fields at the top of my header page in Adobe brackets, the colour of the code doesn't change so I am guessing it isn't allowed there.

Would I set something up in functions.php ?

EDIT: Adding code example - I have a few fields to add but obvs just need to get one right. As I mentioned, cannot add ref to ACF in the file as you normally do, it doesn't work the same.

```
  <div class="pull-right hidden-sm">


 <h3>Recruitment: <a href="tel:<?php echo $recruitment_number_ctc; ?>"><?php echo $recruitment; ?></a></h3>
```

Comment: Please can you write the code in details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you put the following code for displaying content of custom filed?

```
<?php the_field('filed_name'); ?>
```

Comment: Will try that now...

Comment: OMG - that worked....awesome :) :) :) cheers very much!

Comment: So you can now see your content right?

Comment: Yes, it's all working great, love it!

Comment: It's only displaying on the home page as that's where I added them.  I can't add a rule to the custom fields for that page or they will apply across all pages. How do I get the custom field to be global in the header?

Comment: If this header file is included in all pages then it's showing in all pages

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57816/discussion-between-tarun-modi-and-tracy).